# Script firing but no results

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, greasemonkey, blogger

I wrote a GreaseMonkey script to add a button to blogger.com's HTML view.  I have alerts all over the place so I know that everything is running.

The strange thing is that it fires twice, slightly differently each time.
When I navigate to a blogger.com post edit, the script fires first on a black page and goes through all of the alerts in the right order including the "inside" one.

On the second run after the page loads, every alert except the "inside" one runs and no errors are produced.

```
 // ==UserScript==
 // @name  Blogger: Remove HTML Space
 // @include  http://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID*editor/target*\
 // ==/UserScript=

 function contentEval(source) {
   // Check for function input.
   alert("asdas");
   if ('function' == typeof source) {
     // Execute this function with no arguments, by adding parentheses.
     // One set around the function, required for valid syntax, and a
     // second empty set calls the surrounded function.
     source = '(' + source + ')();'
   }

   alert("asdas2");
   // Create a script node holding this  source code.
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   alert("asdas3");
   script.setAttribute("type", "application/javascript");
   alert("asdas4");
   script.textContent = source;
   alert("asdas5");

   // Insert the script node into the page, so it will run, and immediately
   // remove it to clean up.
   alert("asdas6");
   document.body.appendChild(script);
   alert("asdas7");
 }

  alert("test")
  contentEval(function(){ alert("inside"); document.getElementById("postingHtmlToolbar").firstChild.innerHTML += '<div id="SP" class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button" title="SP" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button-outer-box"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button-inner-box"><button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(\'postingHtmlBox\').value = document.getElementById(\'postingHtmlBox\').value.replace(/&amp;nbsp;/g, \' \');"><b>SP</b></button></div></div></div>'});

 alert("testw");
```

Does blogger.com have an anti-script injection thingy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About firing twice:**

If the page contains `<iframe>`s, userscript will fire in each of them.

You need to determine if you are inside `<iframe>` or not. The simplest way to fire only in main page, and not iframes, is to wrap all code with:

```js
if(top==self)
{
  ...
}
```

To see if there are `<iframe>s` in the page (either hardcoded in HTML or dynamically generated) I always use AdBlock Plus ("Open blockable items" dialog).

I'm not sure however why the second "inside" alert does not launch. I've created a simple HTML page containing `<iframe>` and I get two alerts fired.

**About the script generally:**

You're doing double work here. You don't have to wrap everything to execute the script. What Greasemonkey does is executing the code lines after page loads (on `DOMContentLoaded`). So you don't have to create `<script>` tag, set it's body and append to document. You can just write

`document.getElementById("postingHtmlToolbar").firstChild.innerHTML += ...`

and it should do what you want (you don't need `contentEval` function at all).

I don't have any blog on blogger so I can't log and see any URL and the problematic behavior, but playing step by step with the code should be enough to debug.

**Edit 2:**

Seems that you should change `firstChild` to `firstElementChild`.

- [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.firstChild) returns `Node`
- [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.firstElementChild) returns `Element`.

There is `innerHTML` property in `Element` (since Firefox 3.5), but not in `Node`. 
Yeah, it's really inconsistent and annoying at times. I've come into similar problem recently.

**Edit 3:**

There's a couple of things there. Please don't tell me it doesn't work still :)

```js
var func = function() {
    var obj = document.getElementById("postingHtmlToolbar");
    if(obj !== null){ // only if object exists, so we don't have errors
       //alert(obj);
       obj.style.display = 'block'; // it's hidden by default
       obj.firstElementChild.innerHTML += "FOO";
    }
 }

 window.setTimeout(func, 3000); // execute with delay -- let's give Google's JS time to be loaded first
```

Comment: Interesting to know, still if gives me no ideas about why my script is not doing what it is supposed to do.

All in all I do not care if my script fires 100 times as long as it eventually works.
Do you think it is possible that the problem is occurring only because of the multiple runnings?

Comment: I didn't look much in detail at your script before, please see the edit, and say precisely what happens and what should have happened. The problem is with appending HTML, or the button click? Does `document.getElementById("postingHtmlToolbar").firstChild.innerHTML += "FOO" ` work?

About firing multiple times, I think each execution is in separate page context, so they should not affect each other (but I'm not entirely sure).

Comment: @edit: I don't think that greasemonkey can do things like that, it cannot directly edit the page.
Don't ask me why GM cannot just come with a easy way to run code you 100% trust but instead for security reasons I cannot understand they restrict what you can do.

Comment: Sorry, appending; None of the page edits do anything but script passes over the and continues running.

Comment: It's true that Greasemonkey code can't do directly all the things the normal JS can, but GM can do most of them, and in some others, you need to do minor tweaks only. I highly recommend to read [this](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/network/2005/11/01/avoid-common-greasemonkey-pitfalls.html?page=1).

Comment: @edit 2: I tried it but it did not work.
More testing and this is what I got. The first execution is the top but this one does NOT have a postingHtmlToolbar only the second running has this.
During the first running I can inject code (but it disappears by the time the entire page has loaded) but in the second running it does not work at all it simply skips the code injection step (and preventing the script from running in either of these frames has no effect).

Comment: Concerning *During the first running I can inject code (but it disappears by the time the entire page has loaded)* -- curious; you can try `var myfunc = function(){ // do the stuff}; window.setTimeout(myfunc, 5000)` but I'm not sure whether this will help. Huh I guess I will create a blog on blogger to see what's going on :)

Comment: How do you access `http://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=...`? I've tried typing it manually, but gives 404 error. Can't find any links in navigation.

Comment: @edit 3:
That last edit actually works!
Sorry no response for the longest time (I feel like an ass), I gave up on this and then for some reason did not use this site again until now.

Answer (score 0):

GM can directly modify a webpage that's the usefulness of GM

That `<button>` tag... didn't you mean INPUT?

I believe is executing twice because doing this method, which I guess is your workaround for not being able to directly modifying the page.

What you're doing is that you're creating a Named Anonymous function, which if you're not very experienced in JS then "wow" for coming up with that. This would be the issue:

```
if ('function' == typeof source) {
   // Execute this function with no arguments, by adding parentheses.
   // One set around the function, required for valid syntax, and a
   // second empty set calls the surrounded function.
   source = '(' + source + ')();'
}
```

When you set SOURCE between the + + you are calling the function, because as you're concatenating and as a function is not a string then concat is trying to coerce it, for that it executes the function, but then at the end the empty () executes again, later not in the concat. I didn't test it but I do believe that's happening.

So jakub is right in pointing out that the complexity of your code is unnecessary and in the end is giving you errors.